# Spring DataSource with embedded HSQL in memory database and hibernate create-drop ordering on Linux

Tags: linux, spring, hibernate, hsqldb, sessionfactory

I am using Spring 3.1 with annotations to create a DataSource that uses embedded HSQL.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
    EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean bean = new EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean();
    bean.setDatabaseType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL);
    bean.afterPropertiesSet();
    DataSource object = bean.getObject();
    return object;
}
```

I am also configuring a SessionFactory like this

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource)
        .setNamingStrategy(namingStrategy())
        .addProperties(hibernateProperties)
        .addAnnotatedClass(Some.class)
        .buildSessionFactory();
    logger.info("Created session factory: " + sessionFactory + " with dataSource: " + dataSource);
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

The problem is if I create some other beans using @Component in which I populate the database, the SQL script fails because the database has not been created. My hibernate.properties includes the following line to generate DDL

```
properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
```

So it is some sort of ordering issue with bean creating. However this problem only occurs in Linux (Kubuntu 12.04) and not on Windows 7!

Answer (score 1):

I have worked out that in my @Component bean which populates the database I had to add the @DependsOn annotation like this

```
@Component
@DependsOn({"dataSource", "sessionFactory"})
public class DevSqlPopulator {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are calling a `InitializingBean` method `afterPropertiesSet` method yourself instead of letting Spring call it once all the properties are cleanly set. Try doing this instead:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean dataSource() throws Exception {
    EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean bean = new EmbeddedDatabaseFactoryBean();
    bean.setDatabaseType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL);
    return bean;
}
```

Now it is a clean factory bean and Spring will take care of the rest of the lifecycle.